# How to use a "sudo" with password command in a python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sudo

I need to run a sudo command in my script to turn on and off network connections for an script I'm doing.
The password is plain text in the code for this example, but it will be in a jumbled for in a hidden file for the real program.

I tried multiple online examples of code, including popen and call,and nothing worked, but they didnt work and I dont really understand how they work.

```
def run_script(script, stdin=None):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['sudo' , 'bash', '-c', script],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.communicate(b'password')
command = "ip link set enp6s0 down"
run_script(command)
```

The script runs, but it wont actually do anything. No error.

Comment: Does just running your python code with sudo not work?

Comment: as @gst1502 said, you probably don't want to be doing what you're trying to do.  if you **really really** can't find another way to do this, maybe set up a custom rule in `sudoers` that allows that specific `ip link` command to be run by your user without authentication, but note that anything else could also run this at any time

Answer (score 0):

sudo has a parameter called '-S', below helps:

```
sudo bash -c 'your script' -S your_password
```